# What is the symbolic solution to the equation?

Tags: lambert-w

I have been trying to solve this nonlinear equation for sometime now to no avail. I have tried Mathematica and matlab as well. But I believe that a solution exist in terms of x (probably using the Lambert W function).
This is the equation below.

$b\cdot x^a+d\cdot \ln(1+c\cdot x)+\ln(1+(e^p-1)\cdot (1-u))/p=0$

Please, I will be grateful if the solution $x$ is in term of other variables. Thank you.

Comment: @Thomas Andrew, Variable x is the solution or root of the equation.

Comment: @Thomas Andrew, thanks for the correction.

Comment: x is not in the rightmost term, so it can be replaced by 1 with scaling of b and d. At this point, the Lambert W function might be applicable.